# How to know the number of selected in option

Tags: jquery

This is the HTML

```
<select>
  <option value="1">test 1</option>
  <option value="2">test 2</option>
  <option value="3">test 3</option>
  <option value="4" selected="selected">test 4</option>
</select>
```

How can I know the length/number of the option selected? In html the selected is in 3.

so far this is [what I tried](https://jsfiddle.net/rv11tewg/1/)

```
$("select").on("change", function() {
  var td = $(this);
  $("div").on("click", function() {
    var x = $("select").find("option:selected").length;
    var y = $("select").find("option[value='"+x+"']").length;
    $("span").text(x);
    td.prop('selectedIndex',x);
  });
});
```

Comment: `$("select option:selected").length` in your case it will be 1 since it is not set to multiple select

Comment: @guradio already tried that but as you can see it return 1 instead of 3

Comment: i doubt you can select 3 from that select

Comment: @guradio I think hes looking to use `index()` to get the requested result.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen i dont know but he clearly mention that he wants `length/number` .. unless he clarifies it then we cant give an exact solution to problem

Comment: @guradio I agree but I guess(know is dangerous) that he doesn't know how to describe it. But with index, the selected option would, in fact, return 3.

Comment: yes it is the index thanks

Comment: Im sorry for my english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the number of the selected, aka in your example, option 4 = number 3. then use the following.

```
$("div").on("click", function() {
  var td = $("select");
  var selected = td.find("option:selected")
  var x = td.find("option").index(selected);
  $("span").text(x);
});
```

This will use `index()` to get that result.

```js
$("div").on("click", function() {
  var td = $("select");
  var selected = td.find("option:selected")
  var x = td.find("option").index(selected);
  $("span").text(x);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="1">test 1</option>
  <option value="2">test 2</option>
  <option value="3">test 3</option>
  <option value="4" selected="selected">test 4</option>
</select>
<div>
  wewewewewew
</div>
<span></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `index()` to get the selected option number.

You can use `$(this).val()` to get the selected value.

And you can use `$(this).find("option:selected").text()` to get the selected text.

```js
$("select").on("change", function() {
  var valueSelected = $(this).val();
  var selectedText = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
  var getIndex = $(this).find("option:selected").index();
  console.log('Selected Value: ' + valueSelected);
  console.log('Selected text: ' + selectedText);
  console.log('Selected Index: ' + getIndex)
});

$('div').on('click', function() {
  $('select').trigger('change');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="1">test 1</option>
  <option value="2">test 2</option>
  <option value="3">test 3</option>
  <option value="4" selected="selected">test 4</option>
</select>
<div>
  Click me
</div>
```